# Custom set class gets overwritten/set back to builtin when updating it

Tags: python, class, built-in

I have a custom **set** class that can read and write to a file and otherwise should behave like a normal set.

```py
class FileSet(set):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.elements = {line.strip() for line in open(self.file, "r")}
        super().__init__(self.elements)

    def load(self):
        self.elements = {line.strip() for line in open(self.file, "r")}
        super().__init__(self.elements)

    def save(self):
        with open(self.file, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(list(self)))
```

When using `-=` and `|=` in combination with other *FileSet* objects, they remain *FileSet*s. When updating with a *set* however, they change into a normal *set* again and my custom methods cease to work. `print(type(obj))` will say `<class '__main__.FileSet'>` before updating with a *set* and `<class 'set'>` after.

Is there a way to fix that?

EDIT:
The issue was only when updating the *FileSet* with a dict.keys() (`<class 'dict_keys'>`) set...
Works fine otherwise and can be fixed by enclosing the dict.keys() with `set(dict.keys())`

EDIT:
thanks everyone and especially to @chepner :)

Cheers,
julius

Comment: This code seems to work fine, and the FileSet object updates properly with a set. Can you provide any more info?

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: How exactly are you using `-=` and the like?

Comment: `load` should probably use `self.update(elements)` rather than calling `__init__` again, with `__init__` using `self.load` to include elements from the given file. The signature should be something like `__init__(self, *args, file=None, **kwargs)` to remain compatible with `set.__init__`.

Comment: `self.elements` is entirely unnecessary, as the object itself already holds the same references.

Comment: wow, thanks for all your comments!

The issue was only with a dict.keys()-set as it turns out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed up a quick example of the issue and its solution `set(dict.keys())` here:

```py
dictionary = {"apple": ["fruit", "company"], "house": ["building", "famous doctor"]}
>>> f = FileSet("queue")
>>> print(f)
FileSet({'jumbo', 'dumbo'})
>>> type(f)
<class '__main__.FileSet'>
>>> f |= set(dictionary.keys())
>>> type(f)
<class '__main__.FileSet'>
>>> f
FileSet({'house', 'jumbo', 'dumbo', 'apple'})
>>> f |= dictionary.keys()
>>> type(f)
<class 'set'>
```